# PDO execute is closing my active transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

After debugging some code I've discovered that the `PDO->execute()` function is causing my active transaction to be closed, causing me problems.

Here's how I got to this conclusion:

```
// prepare query
$st = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

// optional bindParams (not executed in my example)

var_dump($this->pdo->inTransaction());  //prints(true)
$success = $st->execute();
var_dump($this->pdo->inTransaction());  //prints(false)
```

I've tried to document myself better on the use of transaction and it seems that only `rollback()` and `commit()` can close it, except maybe for the PDO configuration, in particular the `PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT` attribute.

Here's my only PDO parameters declaration in the whole app:

```
$pdoParams = [
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING, 
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
            \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
        ];
```

I've tried adding `\PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => true` but nothing changes.

For reference the statement I'm trying to `execute()` is a `CREATE TABLE [...]`

**EDIT:**
I should also point out that the query executes well, the database is modified as I expect with the new table created, and the `$success` variable is set to `true`. No exceptions are thrown

Comment: Auto commit is on (by default) and you have not explicitly started a transaction. Why are you emulating prepares? And DDL statements trigger an implicit commit.

Comment: I probably didn't paste an important part of the code, but the transaction is opened like so: $model->pdo->beginTransaction();
It's probably due to some autocomment, I'm working on it.
About prepares I'm not sure I've declared that myself, but it seems it's a performance option?

Comment: EDIT TO ALL:
DDL is what I'm doing indeed, I guess I'll just track the statement I'm doing and manually rollback with a drop table if necessary

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html